# SSRS 2016 (web portal) authorization issue

Tags: reporting-services, authorization, ssrs-2016

I am having a lot of trouble getting a user (other than my own user account) set up to use the web portal on SSRS 2016.  With my user account I can view and manage all the reports, data sources, and other objects but now that I am trying to grant access to another user, it is not working.

First I added an active directory domain group she is part of to the System role then, when that didn't work, I added her group to the System Administrators role.  She was still getting the same error about insufficient privileges so I added her user account explicitly to the System Administrators role but the problem is not resolved.

In the error log at "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS13.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\LogFiles\Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.WebHost_10_04_2016_11_50_41.log" I see log entries like this:
    "Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.WebHost!library!8!10/04/2016-12:56:15:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.AccessDeniedException: , Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.AccessDeniedException: The permissions granted to user 'MYDOMAIN\ThisUser' are insufficient for performing this operation.;"

I guess that means the authentication is working just fine, it is the authorization that is failing.

I am probably doing something silly here since I am not a veteran SSRS administrator.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two sets of permissions you cant grant. System level permissions and item level permissions. You have granted system level permissions to the user which would allow her to manage security etc. You need to provide the user with permissions to view/manage the report. To do this, browse to the folder the reports reside in, click on manage, click on the security tab and grant the user content manager permissions so that they may view reports/manage content

Comment: Thank you for the response!  I went to "Manage Folder" on the Home folder and added this user to a role in there which I think will solve the issue (she has left for the day today so I will have to wait for tomorrow for a test).  Thanks again for your help.